# Expedia application type scroll able tableview or collection view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I checked the expedia application recently and i really like the table view moving,collection view or what ever thing is using moving and infinite scrolling (infinite mean the same feed come again and again if move up or down). Also when user move the cells up and down it move like spinner. So, can any one help me to make such type of animation or view thanks in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bpxn.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following controll .

https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLScrollSelect